# View model to domain model, where to test the mapping?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, extension-methods

I'm currently experimenting with a mapping framework (automapper-like) in a MVC project.

In my controller I map the view model to the domain model (seems like the legit place to do it) using the extensions method "Map" of the framework.

Of course my code won't work if the mapping break (for instance if some property name change and causes mismatch).

But where to test the mapping work as expected?

The controller isn't the "unit" responsible of that. Neither is the View Model nor the Domain Model.

I though I could create my own wrapper (Ioc injectable instance) and unit test it with the mapping of view model to domain model bu it feels kinda awkward (how could code readers know those test need to be performed on specific classes?).

I'm kinda lost.

EDIT: (reflexion on John Mc's answer)

```
using System;
using NSubstitute;
using Models = TestEncodeLines.Models;
using Controllers = TestEncodeLines.Controllers;
using ViewModels = TestEncodeLines.ViewModels;
using Infrastructure = TestEncodeLines.Infrastructure;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests.TestControllers
{
    public class TestActivityController
    {
        private Controllers.ActivityController _controller;

        public TestActivityController()
        {
            _controller = new Controllers.ActivityController();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Save_Project()
        {
            // Arrange
            var viewModel = new ViewModels.ActivitiesViewModel();
            var model = Substitute.For<Models.IActivitiesModel>();
            var mapper =
                Substitute.For<Infrastructure.IMapper<ViewModels.ActivitiesViewModel, Models.IActivitiesModel>>();
            mapper.Map(viewModel).Returns(model);

            // Act
            _controller.SaveActivities(viewModel);

            // Assert
            model.Received().Save();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Save_Project_TestMapping /* Here ??? */ ()
        {
            // Arrange
            var viewModel = new ViewModels.ActivitiesViewModel
            {
                Activities = new[]
                {
                    new ViewModels.ActivitiesViewModel.Project
                    {
                        From = new DateTime(2016, 02, 23, 8, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                        To = new DateTime(2016, 02, 23, 10, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                        Name = "Test"
                    }
                },
                Date = new DateTime(2016, 02, 23, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
            };
            var mapper = new Infrastructure.Mapper<ViewModels.ActivitiesViewModel, Models.IActivitiesModel>();

            // Act
            _controller.SaveActivities(viewModel);

            // Assert
            // Somehow (https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual ??) check the mapping
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your current controller tests, how are you treating the mapping?  Are you mocking it, or actually invoking it?  If you're actually invoking it, then your existing controller tests should fail if something goes wrong with the mapping.  Essentially, ViewModel comes in, Model goes to dependencies and it reverses on the way back.  If *any* of the mappings fail, your existing interactions should fail...

Comment: Mocking it. In the code I pasted here, I've added another (incomplete and maybe out of place) test to invoke the real thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I abstracted the implementing mapping framework to IMappingService which is injected through the constructor. You can then ensure that the required calls are being made to the mapping framework in the controller unit tests.

As for testing the mappings, Automapper has a configuration option which will ensure that your configured mapping profiles won't fall over:

```
AutoMapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()
```

That is not to say that the mappings are correct however.

Could you not just created mapping specific unit tests which focus solely on the mapping part? Why not instantiate your source object and try mapping it to the destination within the unit tests, and assert their correctness there?

Comment: Are you suggesting I do as in the (second test) code I added to my question?

Comment: I would create a dedicated Unit test class for each mapping profile. You're testing the mapping and not the functionality of the controller